# Service exited due to Abort trap: 6 in react-native IOS

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I have react-native 0.40.0. `react-native run-ios` command builds project with success, but then app crashes with notice: **Service exited due to Abort trap: 6**!

I try to launch installed app manually by tapping on it, but it crashes all the time with the same errors in console:

> Feb  5 23:25:23 Tony
>   com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.5050AC21-0E8E-4E59-9561-65AFF770E25A.launchd_sim[42289]
>   (UIKitApplication:org.reactjs.native.example.yawaloo[0x973d][53112])
>   : Service exited due to Abort trap: 6

And that's all, I do not even know where to look. Maybe it's because updating to react-native 0.40?

Any ideas?

P.S. Android works perfectly.

Comment: I also have these problems now, but only on a specifig configuration. Did you ever figure out what was wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I got the same issue here.

It just happen when I install this package: https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker

But it's work when I compile from Xcode. 
but not with "react-native run-ios"

I resolved this issue without:

Drag and drop the ios/ImageCropPickerSDK folder to your xcode project.
Cause it was a problem with frameworks path.

But You still have to:

- Click on project General tab :
- Under Deployment Info set Deployment Target to 8.0
- Under Embedded Binaries click + and add RSKImageCropper.framework and QBImagePicker.framework

And done

Hope it's work for you :-)

Comment: HI thanks! I had the same problem in that running in Xcode would work fine but not with `react-native run-ios` so as you suggested I only had to add the Embedded Binaries click and now it works with `react-native run-ios` thanks :)  I seem to have multiple places where I can select RSKImageCropper.framework.iOS being under `app_name/library/imageCropPicker.xcodeproj/Libraries/RSKImageCropper.xcodeproj/Products` or `imageCropPicker.xcodeproj/Libraries/RSKImageCropper... etc` or `RSKImageCropper.xcodeproj/Products`. Which one should I select from? Thanks again :)

Comment: thanks mate! This should be accepted as the correct answer